# Getting the elevation of 400 million points in the US, how to get the elevation of these points from a dataset?

Tags: data, elevation, usgs

I'm a software engineer working on a game concept that would create the United States in the form of a grid, each grid being 200m x 200m in size with an elevation attached to each corner to create a polygon-looking isometric view. Regardless, I have been looking into the USGS datasets for elevation, but they're currently very fragmented, as there are probably about 2,000+ datasets for the nation.

My question is: How would I be able to get the elevation for these territories? It would be around 400 million points, so I need to have the data available on my local instance. Is there a national data file?

Comment: Please **edit** your question to define "dataset". It appears you may mean "single datafile". If so, I would ask how long you would expect a 100Gb download to take, and how many folks would need to make such a download; this might answer your question.  Given that the DTED-1 and -2 tiles available are free, complete (except over military installations and other sensitive sites), and all sew together nicely (and a number of free applications can easily do that processing), having all the data in one place is probably enough of a kick-start for your endeavor.

Comment: @Vince I'm definitely not against a 100gb download if necessary, as I'm on gigabit corporate internet. I will look into the DTED tiles now, as I've never heard of them.

Comment: My point is that most providers *will* be against such a cumbersome data file; since it's their data, they'll expose it in the format most appropriate for *their* resources.  It's unlikely that you could make effective use of such a massive file anyway, so I don't recommend trying.

Comment: @Vince I eventually went with the SRTM data, thanks for guiding me in the right direction!